# Bootstrap 4 - col vertical alignment not working as expected

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Reading the Bootstrap docs you can get to the [alignment examples section.](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#alignment)

It tells you can use use flexbox alignment utilities to **vertically** and **horizontally** align columns as Bootstrap CSS classes `align-items-start`, `align-items-center` and `align-items-end` but when I'm trying it the content is not vertically aligned as expected with a full height `container`, see the following code:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.fill {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.col {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container fill">
  <div class="row align-items-start">
    <div class="col text-center">
      align-items-start
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row align-items-center">
    <div class="col text-center">
      align-items-center
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row align-items-end">
    <div class="col text-center">
      align-items-end
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- jQuery first, then Tether, then Bootstrap JS. -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I expected to have `align-items-center` content on the vertical middle and `align-items-end` at the bottom of the `container`.

What I'm doing wrong or what I misunderstood?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to vertically align items in `flex-container` you need to give  `height` to `flex-container`.

```
.row{
  min-height:100px;
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.fill {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.col {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.row{
  min-height:100px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container fill">
  <div class="row align-items-start">
    <div class="col text-center">
      align-items-start
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row align-items-center">
    <div class="col text-center">
      align-items-center
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row align-items-end">
    <div class="col text-center">
      align-items-end
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- jQuery first, then Tether, then Bootstrap JS. -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```